# How to invert `git log --grep=<pattern>` or How to show git logs that don't match a pattern

Tags: git, git-log

I want to use `git log` to show all commits that do not match a given pattern. I know I can use the following to show all commits that do match a pattern:

```
git log --grep=<pattern>
```

How do I invert the sense of matching?

I am trying to ignore commits that have "bumped to version ..." in the message.

EDIT: I want my final output to be pretty verbose. e.g. `git log --pretty --stat`. So output from `git log --format=oneline` won't work for me.

Comment: Follow up question on mailing list http://groups.google.com/group/git-users/browse_thread/thread/5128b5e5a5089269

Comment: Git 2.3.1+ (Q1/Q2 2015) will introduce `git log --invert-grep=<pattern>`, which should answer your question. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28523090/6309).

Comment: `git log --grep=<string>` should be released in Git 2.4 (Q2 2015): https://github.com/git/git/blob/9ab698f4000a736864c41f57fbae1e021ac27799/Documentation/RelNotes/2.4.0.txt#L25-L26

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Generate a list of all commits, subtract those whose log messages contain the offending pattern, and feed the result to `git log` with your desired options. In the final stage, a couple of options to `git log` are handy:

> `--stdin`
>   In addition to the *commit* listed on the command line, read them from the standard input.
>
> `--no-walk`
>   Only show the given revs, but do not traverse their ancestors.

You can do it with a single pipeline and process substitution.

```
#! /bin/bash

if (( $# < 1 )); then
  echo >&2 "Usage: $0 pattern [<since>..<until>]"
  exit 1
fi

pattern=$1
shift

git log --format=%H $@ |
  grep -v -f <(git log --format=%H "--grep=$pattern" $@) |
  git log --pretty --stat --stdin --no-walk
```

If you don't want to use bash, you could do it with Perl.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
no warnings "exec";

sub usage { "Usage: $0 pattern\n" }

sub commits_to_omit {
  my($pattern) = @_;

  open my $fh, "-|", "git", "log", "--grep=$pattern", "--format=%H", @ARGV
    or die "$0: exec: $!";
  my %omit = map +($_ => 1), <$fh>;
  %omit;
}

die usage unless @ARGV >= 1;
my $pattern = shift;

my %omit = commits_to_omit $pattern;

open my $all, "-|", "git", "log", "--format=%H", @ARGV
  or die "$0: exec: $!";

open my $out, "|-", "git", "log", "--pretty", "--stat", "--stdin", "--no-walk"
  or die "$0: exec: $!";

while (<$all>) {
  print $out $_ unless $omit{$_};
}
```

Assuming one of the above is in your PATH as `git-log-vgrep` and with a history of the form

```
$ git lola
* b0f2a28 (tmp, feature1) D
* 68f87b0 C
* d311c65 B
* a092126 A
| * 83052e6 (HEAD, origin/master, master) Z
| * 90c3d28 Y
| * 4165a42 X
| * 37844cb W
|/  
* f8ba9ea V
```

we could say

```
$ git log-vgrep X
```

to get Z, Y, W, and V.

You can also log other branches, so

```
$ git log-vgrep A tmp
```

gives D, C, B, and V; and

```
$ git log-vgrep C tmp~2..tmp
```

yields just D.

One limitation of the above implementations is if you use a pattern that matches all commits, *e.g.*, `.` or `^`, then you'll get HEAD. This is how `git log` works:

```
$ git log --stdin --no-walk --pretty=oneline </dev/null
83052e62f0dc1c6ddfc1aff3463504a4bf23e3c4 Z
```

Answer (score 36):

This will be possible with [Git 2.4+ (Q2 2015)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9ab698f4000a736864c41f57fbae1e021ac27799/Documentation/RelNotes/2.4.0.txt#L25-L26): see [commit 22dfa8a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/22dfa8a23de4bbb274027736edd3bd311dda2981) by [Christoph Junghans (`junghans`)](https://github.com/junghans):

> #### `log`: teach `--invert-grep` option

> "`git log --grep=<string>`" shows only commits with messages that match the given string, but sometimes it is useful to be able to show only commits that do *not* have certain messages (e.g. "show me ones that are not FIXUP commits").
>
> Originally, we had the `invert-grep` flag in `grep_opt`, but because "`git grep --invert-grep`" does not make sense except in conjunction with "`--files-with-matches`", which is already covered by "`--files-without-matches`", it was moved it to revisions structure.
> To have the flag there expresses the function to the feature better.
>
> When the newly inserted two tests run, the history would have commits with messages "`initial`", "`second`", "`third`", "`fourth`", "`fifth`", "`sixth`"
> and "`Second`", committed in this order.
> The commits that does not match either "`th`" or "`Sec`" is "`second`" and "`initial`". For the case insensitive case only "`initial`" matches.
>
> ```
> --invert-grep
> ```
>
> Limit the commits output to ones with log message that do not match the pattern specified with `--grep=<pattern>`.

Example:

I first grep message with "sequencer" in them:

```
vonc@voncm C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\git

> git log -2 --pretty="tformat:%s" --grep=sequencer
Merge branch 'js/sequencer-wo-die'
sequencer: ensure to release the lock when we could not read the index
```

If I want messages with *no* sequencer:

```
> git log -2 --pretty="tformat:%s" --grep=sequencer --invert-grep
Second batch for 2.11
Merge branch 'js/git-gui-commit-gpgsign'
```

---

Warning: this inverts only patterns specified by `--grep`.
It will *not* invert anymore header matches, like `--author`, `--committer`, starting Git 2.35+ (Q1 2022).
See an example in "[equivalence of: `git log --exclude-author?`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70644305/6309)".

---

Note that `git -P log -1 --invert-grep` could segfault:

Giving "`--invert-grep`" and "`--all-match`" without "`--grep`" to the "[`git log`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/91d3d7e6e2be4aad74c5c602ed4988fbb1d82960/Documentation/git-log.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log))</sup> command resulted in an attempt to access grep pattern expression structure that has not been allocated, which has been corrected with Git 2.39 (Q4 2022).

See [commit db84376](https://github.com/git/git/commit/db84376f981c64a1577d17d99918b2ef65a07a11) (11 Oct 2022) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 91d3d7e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/91d3d7e6e2be4aad74c5c602ed4988fbb1d82960), 21 Oct 2022)</sup>

> ### [`grep.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/db84376f981c64a1577d17d99918b2ef65a07a11): remove "extended" in favor of `"pattern_expression",` fix segfault
>
> <sup>Reported-by: orygaw</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Since [79d3696](https://github.com/git/git/commit/79d3696cfb438467749160481c6119e43d4d2851) ("`git-grep`: boolean expression on pattern matching.", 2006-06-30, Git v1.4.2-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/405a99a67f4e9d42ea5f31322dcd23020e499f2f)) the `"pattern_expression"` member has been used for complex queries (AND/OR...), with `"pattern_list"` being used for the simple OR queries.
> Since then we've used both `"pattern_expression"` and its associated boolean "extended" member to see if we have a complex expression.
>
> Since [f41fb66](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f41fb662f57abccf24d036bb0fd4294eb72261af) (revisions API: have release_revisions() release , 2022-04-13, Git v2.37.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2da81d1efb0166e1cec7a8582b837994dde6225b) listed in [batch #8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9c897eef06347cc5a3eb07c3ae409970ab1052c8)) (revisions API: have `release_revisions()` release `"grep_filter",` 2022-04-13) we've had a subtle bug relating to that: If we supplied options that were only used for "complex queries", but didn't supply the query itself we'd set `"opt->extended",` but would have a `NULL` `"pattern_expression"`.
> As a result these would segfault as we tried to call "`free_grep_patterns()`" from `"release_revisions()`":
>
> ```
> git -P log -1 --invert-grep
> git -P log -1 --all-match
> ```
>
> The root cause of this is that we were conflating the state management we needed in "`compile_grep_patterns()`" itself with whether or not we had an `"opt->pattern_expression"` later on.
>
> In this cases as we're going through "`compile_grep_patterns()`" we have no `"opt->pattern_list"` but have `"opt->no_body_match"` or `"opt->all_match"`.
> So we'd set `"opt->extended` = 1", but not "return" on `"opt->extended"` as that's an "else if" in the same "if" statement.
>
> That behavior is intentional and required, as the common case is that we have an `"opt->pattern_list"` that we're about to parse into the `"opt->pattern_expression"`.
>
> But we don't need to keep track of this "extended" flag beyond the state management in `compile_grep_patterns()` itself.
> It needs it, but once we're out of that function we can rely on `"opt->pattern_expression"` being non-NULL instead for using these extended patterns.

Comment: Hmmm, not working for me: "unrecognized argument: --invert-grep. This is with git 2.9.2.windows.1.

Comment: @KentBoogaart What command did you type? I just used successfully (windows, git 2.10.1) `git log -5 --pretty="tformat:%s" --grep=sequencer` in the git/git cloned repo: it work just fine.

Comment: @Kent I have edited the answer to illustrate the invert-grep works just fine as well. Again, what exact command did you use?

Comment: @VonC ah, yes, I didn't realise it was a switch. I was doing `--invert-grep=foo`. That works for me now, though it's less useful than I'd hoped. Being able to specify "contains this AND doesn't contain this" in one command would be nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

A relatively simple method with a lot of flexibility is to use git log with the -z option piped to awk.  The -z option adds nulls between commit records, and so makes it easy parse with awk:

```
git log --color=always -z | awk -v RS=\\0
```

(color=always is required to keep coloring when the output is a pipe).  Then, its simple to add any boolean expression you want that works on each field.  For example, this will print all entries where the author email is not from fugly.com, and the day of the commit was Sunday:

```
git log --color=always -z | awk -v RS=\\0 '!/Author:.*fugly.com>/ && /Date:.* Sun /'
```

Another nice thing is its you can add in any formatting option or revision range to the git log, and it still works.

One last thing, if you want to paginate it, use "less -r" to keep the colors.

EDIT: changed to use -v in awk to make it a little simpler.

Comment: with perl: `git log -z . |perl -ln0e 'print unless /regex/'`

Answer (score 1):

get a list of all commits containing your result, then filter out their hashes.

```
git log --format=oneline | grep -v `git log --grep="bumped to version" --format="%h"`
```

Answer (score 1):

As with thebriguy's answer, grep also has a -z option to enable it to work with null terminated strings rather than lines. This would then be as simple as inverting the match:

```
git log -z --color | grep -vz "bumped to version"
```

For safety you may want to match within the commit message only. To do this with grep, you need to use pearl expressions to match newlines within the null terminated strings. To skip the header:

```
git log -z | grep -Pvz '^commit.*\nAuthor:.*\nDate:.*\n[\S\s]*bumped to version'
```

Or with colour:

```
git log -z --color | \
  grep -Pvz '^.....commit.*\nAuthor:.*\nDate:.*\n[\S\s]*bumped to version'
```

Finally, if using --stat, you could also match the beginning of this output to avoid matching file names containing the commit string. So a full answer to the question would look like:

```
log -z --color --pretty --stat | \
  grep -Pvz '^.....commit.*\nAuthor:.*\nDate:.*\n[\S\s]*?bumped to version[\S\s]*?\n [^ ]'
```

Note that `grep -P` is described as 'highly experimental' in my man page. It may be better to use `pcregrep` instead which uses libpcre, see [How to give a pattern for new line in grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652568/how-to-give-a-pattern-for-new-line-in-grep). Although `grep -P` works fine for me and I have no idea if `pcregrep` has a -z option or equivalent.

Comment: grep -z on OSX means to read zip compressed input, not handle null terminators.

Comment: Right, -z and -P are not POSIX. So likely this will only work with GNU grep.

Comment: Install gnu core utils on OS X if you want the `-z` option in grep.  I prefer this answer over the accepted one since you can specify any extra options for git log: `pattern=$1; shift; git log -z --color "$@" | grep -vz "$pattern" | tr '\0' '\n' | less -r`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this is not possible to do directly with a single command line; you'd have to do something like Justin Lilly suggests and then run 'git log' on the resulting list of hashes, e.g.,

```
git log --format="%h" | grep -v `git log -1 --grep="bumped to version" --format="%h"` > good-hashes
for h in `cat good-hashes`; do
    PAGER=cat git log -1 --pretty --stat $h
done
```

should do the trick.

Comment: That's too bad. I was hoping there was some option I missed or a new version I should upgrade to. ebneter: I tried your solution, but it did not work for me.

Comment: Hmmm. Worked for me, although I was filtering a different string, of course. I'm curious about what didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by VonC the best option is if you can update to Git 2.4.0 (which is currently on RC2). But even if you can't do that there is no reason for elaborate scripts. A (gnu) awk one-liner should do it. `git log` has the useful `-z` option to separate commits by a NUL-character which makes it easy to parse them:

```
git log -z --pretty --stat | awk 'BEGIN{ RS="\0"; FS="\n\n" } !match($2, /<pattern>/)'
```

If you don't have gnu awk, you probably should at least install that. Or port this script to your specific awk version, which I leave as an exercise for the reader ;-).

Answer (score -1):

```
git log --pretty --stat | grep -v "bumped to version"
```

Comment: That won't work since --pretty --stat will produce multiple lines per commit.