# What is the meaning of :/ (colon, forward slash) in the 2.0 version of git add --update syntax?

Tags: git

I upgraded Git a couple months ago and since then I've been receiving the following deprecation notice upon attempting `git add --update`:

> Warning: The behavior of 'git add --update (or -u)' with no path
>   argument from a subdirectory of the tree will change in Git 2.0 and
>   should not be used anymore. To add content for the whole tree, run:
>
> git add --update :/   (or git add -u :/)
>
> To restrict the command to the current directory, run:
>
> git add --update .   (or git add -u .)
>
> With the current Git version, the command is restricted to the current
>   directory.

The warning itself makes perfectly good sense, and it's saved me some resetting. I've gotten used to typing the `.` or `:/`, but still find the latter quite strange because it's unlike any other command line syntax I've encountered. The `.` is pretty token: it just means "current directory", like in `find .`, but `:/`... never seen that except in this context. What does it mean?

I keep thinking of it as an emoticon, and certainly that's not the case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Edit, Nov 2019**: I've replaced this answer as the original was more wrong than right, really.

The `:/` syntax for `git add` uses what Git calls a *pathspec*.  Pathspecs are defined in [the gitglossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary).  It's worth mentioning that `:` and `:/` have an entirely different meaning in [gitrevisions syntax](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), which is used by many other commands, but not by `git add`.  For these other uses, see [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35342525/1256452).

In pathspecs, the colon character `:` is supposed to be followed by either the *long form* or the *short form* of various  modifiers.  After the modifiers, whatever is left over is either a pattern, or a simple string that gets treated as a file name.

`:/` uses the short form.  In the short form, each recognized character after the colon has some special meaning.  The `/` character means *at the top of the work-tree*.<sup>1</sup>

Any *unrecognized* characters after the colon are part of the left-over stuff.  In this case, the entire sequence is colon-and-slash, so nothing is left over.  However, if you wrote `:/README`, that would mean *the file README in the top of the work-tree*.

That is, suppose you're in the sub-directory (sub-folder) named `sub/`, and it has a `README` file as well.  Then:

```
git add README
```

adds `sub/README` (because you're *in* `sub`), but:

```
git add :/README
```

or:

```
git add ../README
```

adds the top-level file.

For each short-form expression, there's a long-form variant.  There are long-form variants that do not have short-forms, though.  To use the long-form variant, write a colon, then an open parenthesis `(`, then as many long-form names as you like, separated by commas.  End the sequence with a close parenthesis `)`.<sup>2</sup>  For instance, you can write `:(top,icase)readme` to mean *a file named `readme`, or `ReadMe`, or `README`, or any other crazy mixed case, at the top of the work-tree*.  Some command-line interpreters may require quotes around parenthesized expressions: `git add ":(top,icase)readme"`.

The *empty* string, in this particular case, has the same meaning as `.` to Git.  So `:/:` or `:(top)` means the same as `:/:.` or `:(top).`.  This names *every file in the work-tree*.<sup>3</sup>  Leaving off the terminating `:` in the pathspec syntax is OK, so `:/` also means *every file in the work-tree*.

---

<sup>1</sup>There are—at least currently—only two other special characters, `!` and `^`, which both mean "exclude".  So with the colon form, you can write `:/` or `:^` or `:!`, or combine them with `:/!`.

You can terminate the short form with a second colon, i.e., you can write `:/:!` if you want to add the file named `!` that is at the top of the work-tree.  The pathspec `:/!:!` means *do not add the file `!` that is at the top of the tree*; this would only be meaningful if you said to add multiple top-of-tree files, e.g., `git add :/!:! :/:.` would add all files except the top-level file `!`.

<sup>2</sup>**Do not** add another colon at the end of the long form.  That is, `:/:` is correct, and `:(top)` is correct, but `:(top):` is wrong!  This trips me up now and then.

<sup>3</sup>The usual `.gitignore` rules apply, of course.  Remember that any *tracked* file—any file that is in the index right now—is never ignored!

---

#### Sidebar: removed files

As I recall, Git 1.x and 2.0 differ in treatment of files that *were* in the previous commit, *are* currently tracked (i.e., are present in the index, visible with `git ls-files --stage` for instance), but—for whatever reason—are not in the work-tree right now.

The behavior in Git 2.0 is that files removed from the work-tree tend to get removed from the index.  For instance, suppose we run:

```
$ git checkout master
```

and get a file named `file` in the work-tree as a result of the tip commit of `master` containing the file named `file`.  Then we do:

```
$ rm file
```

so that `file` *is* still in the index but is no longer in the work-tree.  A `git status` at this point will say:

```
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    file

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Various forms of `git add` will now *remove* the file `file` from the index.  That includes `git add :/` as well as `git add file`:

```
$ git add :/
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    file
```

If you don't want this removal "added" to the index, you have a number of options, including the `--ignore-removal` option:

```
$ git reset --hard
HEAD is now at 29c2e68 initial
$ git add --ignore-removal :/
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

So if you are using `:/` but want to skip updating (i.e., removing) removed files, use `--ignore-removal`.  The default in Git 2.x is to "add the removal" as well.

Comment: Thank you for the update, but I just confirmed by updating some plugins, and "`:/` also means every file in the work-tree" doesn't seem to be true for me - it really does seem to add only all modified and newly-added files, and also seems to be leaving out those that have been deleted. See here: https://imgur.com/a/qOJ6KF0.

Comment: @Hashim: Your output in the imgur link suggests that files deleted from the work-tree are now also deleted from the index, which is what one would expect here.  Which Git version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.2.1. My point is that running `git add :/` seems to add only those files that have been modified rather than all of the files in my Git repo, which seems to conflict with this answer's assertion that "`:/` means every file in the work-tree".

Comment: @Hashim: If a file in your work-tree is unmodified and therefore matches the copy that is already in the index, how did you determine whether Git *did* copy it into the index, leaving it unchanged in the index, vs whether Git did *not* copy it into the index, leaving it unchanged in the index?

Comment: Note that if a file is *ignored*, i.e., is not in the index now *and* is listed in a `.gitignore`, `git add` will *not* add the file to the index unless forced.

Comment: Are you saying that the list of files in my screenshot is not a complete list of files that Git has staged?

Comment: `git status` compares the `HEAD` commit to the index. Whatever is *different* here is listed as *staged for commit*. For files that match, `git status` says nothing! Then, `git status` compares the index to the work-tree. Whatever is *different* here is listed as *not staged for commit*. For files that match, `git status` says nothing. (If `git status` listed every file that is in the index, it would always list every file! If you want that, use `git ls-files`, perhaps with `--stage` to see the extra detail.)

Comment: I see. I suppose what I'm wondering is whether continuing to use `git add :/` in the way that I am is bad practice. I assumed that because `git add :/` looks for every file in the worktree then it is also committing and pushing all those files. If this isn't the case, then no extra data is being unnecessarily sent over and there shouldn't be anything wrong, as it effectively only stages, commits and pushes the modified changes only, right?

Comment: You always commit all files. Commit snapshots re-use existing frozen-and-compressed files whenever all the data match, so there's no cost to re-committing the same file. `git push` does not push *files*; it pushes *commits* (which then bring files along as needed). Aside from the time needed to run `git add :/` or `git add -u` to scan for which files need new compressed images written, there's no real advantage or disadvantage to that vs just running a few individual `git add`s.

Answer (score 2):

The `:/` is not the only new syntax, you also have

```
:!
:(exclude)
```

[Making 'git log' ignore changes for certain paths](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5685007/#21079437)

So the `:` signifies that a pathspec is immediately following. Then you have `/`, also known as the
[root directory](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_directory), or perhaps in this case representing the root of the repository.

Answer (score 2):

The [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21954767/1728537) is not completely correct. In the context of `git-add`, the `:/` cannot be a revision. It is a *pathspec*. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22049939/1728537) to the related question "[What does "git add -A :/" do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047909/what-does-git-add-a-do)".

*pathspec* is defined in [gitglossary(7)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html).

Comment: You're quite right and I've replaced my answer. Not sure how this escaped my attention for 5 years...

Answer (score 1):

The `:/` notation evolves in git 2.8 (March 2016) with the '`^{/!-<negative pattern>}`' notation: `:/!-foo`

See [commit 0769854](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0769854f3db2c09c8b5993ea023ea07ddc1eb6eb) (31 Jan 2016), and [commit 06b6b68](https://github.com/git/git/commit/06b6b68ff943de9e5c2f537807c054cd536731d1) (10 Jan 2016) by [Will Palmer (`wpalmer`)](https://github.com/wpalmer).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit fb79532](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fb795323ce3ce5a358f8e55641777b9cdbeab846), 10 Feb 2016)</sup>

> To name a commit, you can now use the `:/!-<negative pattern>` regex
>   style, and consequentially, say

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD^{/!-foo}
```

> and it will return the hash of the first commit reachable from HEAD,
>   whose commit message does not contain "`foo`".
>   This is the opposite of the existing `<rev>^{/<pattern>}` syntax.
>
> The specific use-case this is intended for is to perform an operation, excluding the most-recent commits containing a particular marker.
>   For example, if you tend to make "work in progress" commits, with messages beginning with "`WIP`", you work, then it could be useful to diff against "the most recent commit which was not a `WIP` commit".
>   That sort of thing now possible, via commands such as:

```
$ git diff @^{/!-^WIP}
```

> The leader '`/!-`', rather than simply '`/!`', to denote a negative match,
>   is chosen to leave room for additional modifiers in the future.

The [new `git/revisions` doc](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0769854f3db2c09c8b5993ea023ea07ddc1eb6eb/Documentation/revisions.txt#L150-L159) now states:

> To match messages starting with a string, one can use e.g. '`:/^foo`'.
>   The special sequence '`:/!`' is reserved for modifiers to what is matched:
>
> - '`:/!-foo`' **performs a negative match**,
> - while '`:/!!foo`' matches a literal '!' character, followed by 'foo'.
> - Any other sequence beginning with '`:/!`' is reserved for now.

Comment: This appears to be a documentation error. `:/<text>` now appears to always search for a path named `<text>` in the tree object (which, honestly, sounds much better than searching for commit messages). `^{/<text>}` performs the search previously described by `:/<text>` - and yes, `HEAD^{/<text>}` it appears can match HEAD itself. `HEAD^^{/<text>}` performs the behaviour that the documentation describes as `HEAD^{/<text>}`

Comment: @WillPalmer Strange: the most recent revision of this documentation still mention commit message: https://github.com/git/git/blob/048abe1751e6727bfbacf7b80466d78e04631f94/Documentation/revisions.txt#L185-L197

Comment: I spotted that as well, and have sent a message to the mailing list reporting the possible bug.

Comment: @WillPalmer https://public-inbox.org/git/CAAKF_ubf3EMK6sTrvZo1OSVHLiLjnY=S=W7s1CNCkZLSteaa+g@mail.gmail.com/T/#u: got it.