# Why isn't the pathspec magic :(exclude) excluding the specified files from git log's output?

Tags: git, git-log

This is a follow-up to [Ignore files in git log -p](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339828/ignore-files-in-git-log-p) and is also related to [Making 'git log' ignore changes for certain paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685007/making-git-log-ignore-changes-for-certain-paths).

I'm using Git 1.9.2. I'm trying to use the pathspec magic `:(exclude)` to specify that some patches should not be shown in the output of `git log -p`. However, patches that I want to exclude still show up in the output.

Here is a minimal working example that reproduces the situation:

```sh
$ cd ~/Desktop
$ mkdir test_exclude
$ cd test_exclude
$ git init
$ mkdir testdir
$ printf "my first cpp file\n" > testdir/test1.cpp
$ printf "my first xml file\n" > testdir/test2.xml
$ git add testdir/
$ git commit -m "added two test files"
```

Now I want to show all patches in my history expect those corresponding to XML files in the `testdir` folder. Therefore, following [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21079437/2541573), I run

```sh
$ git log --patch -- . ":(exclude)testdir/*.xml"
```

but the patch for my `testdir/test2.xml` file still shows up in the output:

```bash
commit 37767da1ad4ad5a5c902dfa0c9b95351e8a3b0d9
Author: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Date:   Mon Aug 18 12:23:56 2014 +0100

    added two test files

diff --git a/testdir/test1.cpp b/testdir/test1.cpp
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..3a721aa
--- /dev/null
+++ b/testdir/test1.cpp
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+my first cpp file
diff --git a/testdir/test2.xml b/testdir/test2.xml
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..8b7ce86
--- /dev/null
+++ b/testdir/test2.xml
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+my first xml file
```

What am I doing wrong? What should I do to tell `git log -p` not to show the patch associated with all XML files in my `testdir` folder?

Comment: For what it's worth, it sure looks like this is supposed to work.  Pathspecs are not very well documented though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nevermind. The problem appears to have been fixed in Git 1.9.5 (more specifically, in [commit `ed22b4173bd8d6dbce6236480bd30a63dd54834e`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed22b4173bd8d6dbce6236480bd30a63dd54834e)). The toy example in my question above works as expected in Git 2.2.1:

```sh
$ git --version
git version 2.2.1
$ mkdir test_exclude
$ cd test_exclude/
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/jubobs/Desktop/test_exclude/.git/
$ mkdir testdir
$ printf "my first cpp file\n" > testdir/test1.cpp
$ printf "my first xml file\n" > testdir/test2.xml
$ git add testdir/
$ git commit -m "added two test files"
[master (root-commit) 5429d04] added two test files
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 testdir/test1.cpp
 create mode 100644 testdir/test2.xml

$ git log --patch -- . ":(exclude)testdir/*.xml"
commit 5429d047f140f96c5d6167d083fc1a5eab05fb19
Author: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Date:   Fri Dec 26 23:40:18 2014 +0100

    added two test files

diff --git a/testdir/test1.cpp b/testdir/test1.cpp
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..3a721aa
--- /dev/null
+++ b/testdir/test1.cpp
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+my first cpp file
```

As you can see, there is no mention of `test2.xml` in the output of that `git log` command, as desired.