# Find the latest file(s) added to a git repository with name(s) matching a given wildcard pattern

Tags: git, wildcard

I am looking at the git repository of a rather large project whose test-suite is sprinkled across several files in various sub-directories. All test case filenames follow the same wildcard pattern (say, `test-*`). Given this, how do I list the newest test cases committed to the repository?

I'm not too particular about whether those commits *create* a test case or just *last modified* a test case. Either is fine. I just want to see some of the newer tests written/modified by the project's contributors.

As far as I can make out:

```
git log -- */test*
```

Only shows commits that touch test cases one level down in the hierarchy, and not lower.

Comment: I just tried `git log -- */test*` on a dummy repo, and it shows log entries in which, for instance, `foo/bar/test1.py` was created. Which version of Git are you using? I'm running Git 2.0.1.

Comment: @Jubobs - which version of git are you running? Mine (1.8.4) does not.

Comment: I'll post my baby example showing that it works in Git 2.0.1. Perhaps the source changed between your version and mine...

Comment: @kev, there was nothing particularly wrong with your (now deleted) answer. The diff works pretty fine.

Comment: @Jubobs - Great. I am not going to bother upgrading my git, but probably others will find it useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `*/test*` matches some file(s), your shell will expand this expression.  Try:

```
echo */test*
```

at the shell prompt.  Compare, for instance:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ mkdir empty
$ cd empty
$ echo */test*
*/test*
```

`/tmp/empty` is empty so `*/test*` matches nothing.  But then:

```
$ mkdir dir; touch dir/test.file
$ echo */test*
dir/test.file
```

So, if you have nothing matching `*/test*` and you run:

```
$ somegitcommand */test*
```

the git command will see `*/test*` as its argument; but if you have something that matches, the git command will see `dir/test.file` as its argument.  The `*`s have vanished.

The fix is really super-simple: quote the `*/test*` part:

```
$ git log --oneline -- '*/test*'
```

Now `git log` will see `*/test*`, rather than `dir/test.file`, and git will be able to do recursive matching.

---

It's worth mentioning that not all shells behave the same way.  In csh and tcsh, if there is no match for a shell glob like `*/test.*`, you get:

```
> rm -r dir
> echo */test*
echo: No match.
```

In bash, you can choose the behavior:

```
bash$ echo */test*
*/test*
bash$ shopt -s failglob
bash$ echo */test*
bash: no match: */test*
```

(in fact you can do the same in csh and tcsh; it's just inverted: `set nonomatch` and the `*/test*` is passed through to `echo`).

Also, this illustrates the difference between the shell's wildcard globbing (which does not recurse into subdirectories) and git's (which does).  See [Jubobs' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25457622/1256452) and try (in the shell) `echo */*/test*` vs `echo */test*` (all without quotes).  Some shells have recursive globbing that can be enabled in various ways, such as using `**` to indicate recursion is desired: `echo **/test*`.

---

One last note: git's wildcard matching has changed somewhat from one version to another, especially in `.gitignore` files.  Specifically, `**` meaning "zero or more directories" (specifically in `.gitignore` files) was added to git in [version 1.8.2](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.2.txt).

Comment: Weird. It seems to work without quotes in my example. Did I miss something?

Comment: @Jubobs: all your test files are several levels down.  Try the `echo */test*` diagnostic! :-)  Note that git's matching allows directories, while the shell's doesn't.

Comment: @Jubobs: exactly.  This is why I actually prefer csh's default of simply failing to run the command: you don't get used to having glob expressions like, e.g., `[a-f][a-f]` pass through because all your own file names are 3 characters long or more, only to have it expand instead unexpectedly for the first time that you're in a directory with a file named `ed`.

Comment: .. taking it in :) I see; the shell expands the glob pattern too soon, if there is a match. But if there is none, it's passed to Git unexpanded and Git interprets the glob pattern differently from how the shell does.

Comment: Could the answer to [this question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362738/why-isnt-the-pathspec-magic-exclude-excluding-the-specified-files-from-git-l) also be an untimely expansion?

Comment: @Jubobs: hm, no, shouldn't be doing globbing in double quotes (variables yes, glob no).

Comment: Amazing catching that shell expansion. I totally forgot about it.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**: This isn't the complete picture; I'm only leaving this answer live because torek makes reference to it in [his much more complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25457637/2541573).

I use Git 2.0.1 in bash, and I can't reproduce the behaviour you're describing: as demonstrated below,

```
git log -1 -- */test*
```

shows commits that add/remove/modify files that match `test*` two levels down the hierarchy of the working tree. Perhaps the way glob patterns are handled changed between v1.8.3 and v2.0.1. Consider updating to a more recent version.

```bash
# set things up
cd ~/Desktop
mkdir babyexample
cd babyexample
git init

# add three test files under foo/bar/
mkdir foo
cd foo
mkdir bar
cd bar
touch test1.py
touch test2.c
touch testmypatience.baz
cd ../..
git add .
git commit -m "add three test files"

# add a README
touch README.md
git add README.md
git commit -m "add README"

# remove test1.py
git rm foo/bar/test1.py
git commit -m "remove Python file"

# modify test2.c
printf "hello\n" > foo/bar/test2.c
git add test2.c
git commit -m "say hello in C file"
```

Then,

```bash
git log --oneline
```

outputs

```
9537199 say hello in C file
20b90f2 remove Python file
494cf11 add README
bfb6686 add three test files
```

whereas

```bash
git log --oneline -- */test*
```

filters the log output as expected:

```
9537199 say hello in C file
20b90f2 remove Python file
bfb6686 add three test files
```

Comment: Hmm, so all this is finally explained by the shell expansion. Because the missing match causes the * to be passed to `git`, which then uses it correctly.

Comment: @ArjunShankar Yes :) I was way off, but torek found the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `git diff` to list all recently changed `tests`:

```
git diff --stat HEAD^ -- '**/test*'
 path/to/test_x        | 17 -----------------
 path/to/test_y        | 1  +
 2 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 17 deletions(-)
```

Comment: Where do you get `3.days.ago` from? I don't think the OP knows the timestamp of the last commit that added test files to the repo.