# Filtering (excluding) git log results by filename extension

Tags: git

I’m looking for a particular string in a git repository, but I’d like my `git log -Swhatever -p` results to exclude any changes made to anything CSS related, e.g. any file with a file extension of `.css` or `.scss`

Is there a filter option or something in `git log` that I’m missing?

So far I’ve got `git log -Swhatever -p -- '*.erb' '*.rb' '*.coffee' '*.js'` as likely suspects for “other kinds of file extensions where my string might be” but I bet I’m going to miss some file extensions.

Comment: Probable duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25362738/1256452 (note in the answer that `:exclude` was broken until recently).

Answer (score 4):

@torek is right!

The way to do this is as simple as:

`git log -Swhatever -p  -- . ':(exclude)*.css' ':(exclude)*.scss'`