# Invalid pathspec magic

Tags: git

When I try to partially stage a file in git, I get the following error message.

```
git add -p mass_scan.py

fatal: Invalid pathspec magic 'prefix:8' in ':(prefix:8)mass_scan.py'
No changes.
```

What does it mean? How can I partially stage a file?

I use git version

```
git version 2.6.2.450.g259b5e6
```

installed directly from source (without package manager). I can still partially add files with `tig`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: Might be worth specifying which version of Git you're using. [Pathspec magic used to be buggy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362738/why-isnt-the-pathspec-magic-exclude-excluding-the-specified-files-from-git-l).

Comment: Is "file" actually "file" or are you not telling us something?

Comment: Please do and try it that way. Also, show the name of the real file. I think it is significant to your issue. Git has a special parameter for most of its programs, `--`, to indicate the start of a path-spec list for a reason.

Comment: Hmm. Have you tried `git add -p -- mass_scan.py`?

Comment: What is `git status` before your command?

Comment: In that case my close vote still holds valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled `git` and the error went away. I don't know what the original problem was, but it works now.

Answer (score 1):

There is another case where the `Invalid pathspec magic` can appear: when the file has multiple attributes declared in a `.gitattributes`.
That is, until Git 2.13 (Q2 2017) which fixes that bug.

See [commit c5af19f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c5af19f9ab4cd8582689ca9d9c84f188f4442d10), [commit b0db704](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b0db70465246bb8309d3d12c9bc34ac3f0c1e203) (13 Mar 2017) by [Brandon Williams (`mbrandonw`)](https://github.com/mbrandonw).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f6c64c6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f6c64c648ade843b44d517b2de41b8b882f112c0), 17 Mar 2017)</sup>

> ### `pathspec`: allow escaped query values
>
> In our own `.gitattributes` file we have attributes such as:
>
> ```
> *.[ch] whitespace=indent,trail,space
> ```
>
> When querying for attributes we want to be able to ask for the exact
>   value, i.e.
>
> ```
> git ls-files :(attr:whitespace=indent,trail,space)
> ```
>
> should work, but the commas are used in the attr magic to introduce
>   the next attr, such that this query currently fails with:
>
> ```
> fatal: Invalid pathspec magic 'trail' in ':(attr:whitespace=indent,trail,space)'
> ```
>
> This change allows escaping characters by a backslash, such that the query
>
> ```
> git ls-files :(attr:whitespace=indent\,trail\,space)
> ```
>
> will match all path that have the value "`indent,trail,space`" for the
>   whitespace attribute.

---

Note: with Git 2.20 (Q4 2018), "`git add ':(attr:foo)'`" is not supported and is supposed to be rejected while the command line arguments are parsed, but was *not* rejected.
It is now

See [commit 84d938b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/84d938b732242e81ec68647994070eb7c34d061f) (18 Sep 2018) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit faadedb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/faadedb19538a9968dd2d607bcab00be1916bd31), 24 Sep 2018)</sup>

> ### `add`: do not accept pathspec magic '`attr`'
>
> [Commit b0db704](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b0db70465246bb8309d3d12c9bc34ac3f0c1e203) (`pathspec`: allow querying for attributes -
>   2017-03-13, Git v2.13.0-rc0) adds new pathspec magic '`attr`' but only with
>   `match_pathspec()`.
>   "`git add`" has some pathspec related code that still does not know about '`attr`' and will bail out:
>
> ```
> $ git add ':(attr:foo)'
> fatal: BUG:dir.c:1584: unsupported magic 40
> ```
>
> A better solution would be making this code support '`attr`'. But I
>   don't know how much work is needed (I'm not familiar with this new magic). For now, let's simply reject this magic with a friendlier message:
>
> ```
> $ git add ':(attr:foo)'
> fatal: :(attr:foo): pathspec magic not supported by this command: 'attr'
> ```
>
> [Update `t6135`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/84d938b732242e81ec68647994070eb7c34d061f/t/t6135-pathspec-with-attrs.sh#L162-L169) so that the expected error message is from the
>   "graceful" rejection codepath, not "oops, we were supposed to reject
>   the request to trigger this magic" codepath.

---

And since Git 2.21 (Q1 2019), that "pathspec magic" is no longer reserved to `git ls-files`, but applies to `git log` and `git grep` too!
The traversal over tree objects has learned to honor "`:(attr:label)`" pathspec match, which has been implemented only for enumerating paths on the filesystem.

See [commit 5a0b97b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a0b97b34c51eaddf39624857f1ac0e7df4ca2e3), [commit 22af33b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/22af33bece7e121b9d535d0a117cd4553b00fe07), [commit 93e2379](https://github.com/git/git/commit/93e23798effba81df218157d97995771adc89668), [commit 67022e0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/67022e02145b3be774febf38e9dc228ed11e6f25), [commit e092073](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e092073d643b17c82d72cf692fbfaea9c9796f11) (18 Nov 2018) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d6f05a4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d6f05a435f9c89f8c9860c7af692942768d81584), 14 Jan 2019)</sup>

> ### `tree-walk`: support `:(attr)` matching
>
> This lets us use `:(attr)` with "`git grep <tree-ish>`" or "`git log`".
>
> `:(attr)` requires another round of checking before we can declare that a path is matched. This is done after path matching since we have lots of optimization to take a shortcut when things don't match.
>
> Note that if `:(attr)` is present, we can't return `all_entries_interesting` / `all_entries_not_interesting` anymore because we can't be certain about that.
>   Not until `match_pathspec_attrs()` can tell us "yes: all these paths satisfy `:(attr)`".
>
> Second note. Even though we walk a specific tree, we use attributes
>   from *worktree* (or falling back to the index), not from `.gitattributes` files on that tree.
>   This by itself is not necessarily wrong, but the user just have to be aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `git add -p` or `git add filename` but not both at the same time.
Should help

Comment: This has the same outcome.