# List commits not touching specific paths

Tags: git

I need to list commits that touch one path in the source tree but not another.

D - head

C - touched *foo* and *bar*

B -  touched *foo*

A - baseline

Between A and D I want a list of all commits touching folder *foo* *unless* they also touch folder *bar*,  in other words, in the example above I would expect to see B but not C.

I tried `git rev-list A..D --exclude='bar' -- foo` but that gives me both B and C still.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing built into Git to do this.  However, it's easy to construct with a small shell script using [the `comm` command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm).  Simply get a list of all commits that affect interesting files, and a second list of all commits that affect files that make the commit uninteresting, then use `comm` to extract the interesting items (those that appear in the first list, but not in both the first and second list).

Hence:

```
git rev-list A..D -- foo > /tmp/list1
git rev-list A..D -- bar > /tmp/list2
comm -23 /tmp/list[12]
```

Note that the "sorted" requirement for `comm` is deliberately violate-able (and is violated here); if your particular `comm` insists on it, you may need to write your own variation.

---

Edit: I tested VonC's suggestion, in Git 2.8.1, by making a new repository with an initial commit with files A/a and B/b:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.8.1
$ git log --oneline --name-status
731a059 both
M       A/a
M       B/b
6894130 B only
M       B/b
b4bb2d8 A only
M       A/a
f134515 initial
A       A/a
A       B/b
```

Adding `-- A` correctly discards the `B only` commit:

```
$ git log --oneline --name-status -- A
731a059 both
M       A/a
b4bb2d8 A only
M       A/a
f134515 initial
A       A/a
```

However, adding `:(exclude):B` has no effect on the selected commits:

```
$ git log --oneline --name-status -- A ':(exclude):B'
731a059 both
M       A/a
b4bb2d8 A only
M       A/a
f134515 initial
A       A/a
```

Commit `731a059`, which touches files A/a and B/b, still appears in the output, as does initial commit `f134515`.  The difference is that when the two commits that also affect B/b are selected, the *file* B/b is omitted.  The original question calls for the *entire commit* to be excluded.

---

Edit 2 (using `comm` and bash's `<(...)` syntax, to omit the temp files):

```
[~/tmp/git-exclude]$ comm -23 <(git rev-list HEAD -- A) <(git rev-list HEAD -- B)
b4bb2d84d633e2254081b7ce99681d92b7974a9d
```

This is the desired output, since only commit `b4bb2` affects *only* the `A` directory.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I had to add `--nocheck-order` to suppress warnings from comm, but that gives me what I was after.

Answer (score 3):

Since [Git 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21079437/6309), and the introduction pathspec magic `:(exclude)` and its short form `:!`, the syntax should be:

```
 git rev-list A..D -- foo ":(exclude)bar"
```

However, this would still list C, even though the files displayed for that commit would not include files with `bar` in its path:

```
 git log --oneline --name-status A..D -- foo ":(exclude)bar"
```

The pathspec exclusion works, but `C` is still listed.

Comment: Does this actually work for this case?  I think exclude simply keeps those files from engaging in selection, rather than *de*-selecting commits.

Comment: @torek at least, I have good result with `git log --oneline --format=%H -- foo :!bar`

Comment: I tried a test and it's not working that way for me (on Git 2.8.1).  It's not what I would expect based on the pathspec documentation, either.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include sample output.  If one just wants to exclude those files (but still keep the commit if it touches explicitly *in*cluded files), `:(exclude):` or `:!` will do the trick.