# exclude syntax for git rev-list working the wrong way around

Tags: git, bash

I am trying to list commits from a branch that do not touch a certain directory, following the advice in [Making 'git log' ignore changes for certain paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685007/making-git-log-ignore-changes-for-certain-paths/21079437#21079437):

```
git rev-list heads/demo ^master -- . ':(exclude)demo'
```

(Note that `demo` is both the name of the branch and of the folder to exclude.)

The result contains all the commits that touch other paths and only excludes those that **only** touch files in the `demo/` directory. What I would like to see instead are only those commits that do not touch any file in the `demo/` directory. To clarify:

```
cc3ecaa define a task for creating the demo app
M   .gitignore
M   Gruntfile.js
A   demo/compile
A   tasks/demo.js
```

currently is included because it contains files outside `demo/`, but I would like it to be excluded because it contains files inside `demo/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk ' !seen[$1]++ && NR!=FNR ' \
    <(git rev-list master..heads/demo -- demo/) \
    <(git rev-list master..heads/demo)
```

or

```
awk ' !NF{ printit=1 } !seen[$1]++ && printit' <<EOD
$(git rev-list master..heads/demo -- demo/)

$(git rev-list master..heads/demo)
EOD
```

or

```
( git rev-list master..heads/demo -- demo/ 
  echo
  git rev-list master..heads/demo ) \
| awk '!NF { ++printit } seen[$1]++ && printit'
```

Comment: I feared that I had to go via awk, but to figure it out for myself would have taken me several hours, so a heartfelt thanks.