# How to list author's inserted lines excluding files?

Tags: git, git-log

I'm abble to list each author's contribution on inserted or deleted lines or character using `git log` like:

`git log --shortstat --author "Steve Jobs"`

But how to recursively exclude specific folders? If I want to list inserted lines of specific users without take into account the folder `test` (and all files it contains) he pushed?

If people had pushed a `node_modules` file, the number of inserted lines will drasticaly grow, I don't want to take them into account.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making 'git log' ignore changes for certain paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685007/making-git-log-ignore-changes-for-certain-paths)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-log%5D+exclude+path

Comment: I've already looked arround your links, but they only show each lines were inserted / deleted of each commit (excluding specifics files, good point).
On very big project with more than 400 commit, should I count each inserted / deleted lines and add them to get the output? no...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally achieved to do it:

To see the total's project inserted and deleted lines for the user `toto` excluding all content from `node_modules`, just do the following:

```
git log --shortstat --author="toto <toto.tata@tutu.tete>" -- . ":\!node_modules" | grep -E "fil(e|es) changed" | awk '{files+=$1; inserted+=$4; deleted+=$6} END {print "files changed: ", files, "lines inserted: ", inserted, "lines deleted: ", deleted }'
```

it will output stat in format:

`files changed:  31 lines inserted:  75293 lines deleted:  25`

In the case you want an overview of each change applied by your coworkers (excluding specidic files) you only have to make a script to run this command with all repository's contributor (can be found with `git log --format='%aN' | sort -u`)

Comment: While this answer works to exclude ``files changed:``, it does not work for the lines inserted or deleted.  Running the same command without the ``(exclude)`` path does not change the line counts.