# libgit2 checkout options.paths ignores negation prefix

Tags: git, libgit2

Using libgit2 I am trying to run git_checkout_tree on all files in my working tree while skipping some specific files.
Filling the git_checkout_options checkout_opts like so

```
char* p[2]= {"*", "!myFile.dat"};
checkout_opts.paths.strings = p;
checkout_opts.paths.count = 2;
```

does still checkout myFile.dat (which is located in the repository root). I tried to stick to the .gitignore pattern syntax. I've compiled libgit2 and tried to get my head around the code base. I see that wildmatch.c defines a NEGATE_CLASS '!' and a NEGATE_CLASS '^'. Using ^myFile.dat doesn't work, unfortunately. Is pattern negation not supported in libgit2 or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [issue 2263](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/2263#issuecomment-407463309), a sparse-checkout is not yet supported with libgit2.

As a result, a `git_checkout_tree` might not support the recent wildmatch ([replacing fnmatch in PR 5110](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/5110) a year ago, June 2019).
No negative path is tested in [`tests/checkout/tree.c`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/2ffa426e1dffc78c64112ea8a4a9796be66462a9/tests/checkout/tree.c).

Comment: Indeed, there's no negation support in the paths for `checkout_opts`.  This is by-design, though I can imagine that this could change to support sparse checkout style paths.

Comment: @EdwardThomson I can understand that, especially considering Git 2.28 revealed negative paths were broken (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21079437/6309)