# How can I exclude a commit and all parents from git-log?

Tags: git

There are many times where I have one project bring another repository in as a subtree. This is great and works fine, but it complicates git-log because I end up seeing this unbelievably-long history associated with the subtree and it's placed *above* the history of my branch, making it much harder to see what's going on in my branch/master/etc.

**Is there a way to tell git-log to ignore all commits reachable by a certain commit?** I'm thinking of making a project-specific pretty-log script that knows some of the commit IDs of the things subtree'd-in so I can have it automatically filter those out and show me a more-useful git-log.

Comment: You can ignore that subdirectory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685007/making-git-log-ignore-changes-for-certain-paths

Comment: Have you read the [documentation of `git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)? The answer to your question is exposed in the second paragraph.

Comment: ... I had not ... and, in hindsight, should have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation with a subtree : @ChrisMaes comment linking to how to ignore a *directory* is a good suggestion.

---

Yes, you tell `git log` to ignore a commit and its parent.

Quoting [`git help log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_description) :

> Thus, the following command:
>
> ```
> $ git log foo bar ^baz
> ```
>
> means "list all the commits which are reachable from `foo` or `bar`, but not from `baz`".

---

At the end of the "Description" paragraph of [`git help log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_description), you can read :

> The command takes options applicable to the [`git-rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) command to control what is shown and how [...]

[`git-rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) will tell you all the details of how you can describe a set of commits.