# Ignore files from git log -S/-G

Tags: git, search, docx, git-log

So when I run `git log -S[string]` or `git log -G[string]`, `git` will try to search `[string]` in various places over all the log. It seems to encounter some old `.docx` files that I had committed once but since then deleted. Somehow `git` isn't happy with that though, since it says either :

```
<[filename].docx> does not seem to be a docx file!
```

or

```
Failed to extract required information from <[filename].docx>!
```

In my particular situation, however, I have never encountered a situation where I would expect results of my `-S`/`-G` search to pop up in those files. Can I just ask `git` to skip them when searching, thus saving time (the search is noticeably slower) and also sparing me the error messages ?

Comment: You mean `--no-textconv`?

Comment: I do, quite exactly ! Thank you ! Feel free to post this as an answer and I will mark it as accepted !

Comment: Though actually, the title of my post was "ignore files", not specifying which kind, and that would also be an interesting question ! In case you happen to know the answer off the top of your head like this.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that you have told Git that, while `*.docx` files are binary and hence not generally readable,<sup>1</sup> Git can *convert* such files *to* plain text, for diff and/or grep purposes, by running some filter program.  Unfortunately this particular filter program can't read these files, perhaps due to format changes.<sup>2</sup>  (It is this program, not Git, that is emitting the error messages.)

> ... files that I had committed once but since then deleted

You haven't deleted them (you literally *can't* delete them): they're still there in the old commits.  Your `git log` is looking through all the commits, including the old ones.

> Can I just ask git to skip them when searching

You can: `git log` takes an optional *pathspec* at the end, and the pathspec can be a [negative pathspec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21079437/1256452), i.e., a pattern that Git should *not* look at.  In this case `:!*.docx` would most likely work as this negative pathspec.  Note that some of these characters are special to various shells, so they may need some tricky quoting.

Apart from this, as [matt noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71600805/ignore-files-from-git-log-s-g#comment126548736_71600805), you can add `--no-textconv` to your `git log` to ignore textconv directives in `.gitattributes` files.  You might also reconsider whether you *want* to use these textconv attributes at all, if they don't work on whatever docx files you have.

---

<sup>1</sup>Some docx files *are* binary due to being compressed, and some are just difficult to read.

<sup>2</sup>There's no single standard docx format.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) for details.