# Is it possible to list the most recent commit id of commited files with a single git command?

Tags: git

I want to find out the most recent commit ID of a list of files. Something like:

```
git last-commit -- file1 file2 file3
file1   456fac456  Sat Jan 6 00:39:39 2024 +0000
file2   7ac362147  Mon Dec 25 10:17:59 2023 +0000
file3   69deba245  Sat Jan 7 23:09:23 2024 +0000
```

I tried `git log -1 -- file1 file2 file3` but it only lists one line for the most recent commit, in this example `file3`.  But I want to see the last commit ID for each file.  I know I can enter a `git log` for each file, but I'd like to do it for multiple files at once.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685007/making-git-log-ignore-changes-for-certain-paths

Comment: I have a script [`set-commit-date.py`](https://git.phdru.name/?p=git-scripts.git;a=blob_plain;f=set-commit-date.py) (see it in my repository https://git.phdru.name/git-scripts.git/). I wrote it for a my own purpose: it parses `git log` once and for every file in a repository it finds a commit where the file was last committed; then it sets the file timestamps to the time of the commit. A little bit more elaborated that the script in [the comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77775107/7976758) by @jthill . I think you can adapt it to your needs — pass a list of files, remove time change…

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I was hoping for some builtin options/commands within git itself. Looks like the only method is via externals commands.

Comment: Git's a tool in a toolbox. Why reimplement all the already-existing tools?

Answer (score 2):

You can write a simple script and store it as `git-last-commit`:

```
#!/bin/sh
for path; do
  printf '%s\t%s\n' "$path" "$(git log --pretty='%h %ad' -1 -- "$path")"
done
```

or define a Git alias:

```
git config --global alias.last-commit '!f() {
for path; do
  printf "%s\t%s\n" "$path" "$(git log --pretty="%h %ad" -1 -- "$path")";
done;
}; f'
```

Comment: Note that this is not very efficient because it will walk the history once for each file.

Answer (score 2):

```
git log --pretty=%h --name-status file1 file2 etc \
| awk 'NF==1{commit=$1} NF==2 && !seen[$2]++ { print commit,$0 }' FS=$'\t'
```