# equivalence of: git log --exclude-author?

Tags: git

At work we have a git repo where the majority of all commits are automated commits by a bot user. There are times when I prefer to view a git log from that repo, but without seeing the auto commits. I guess it could be described as an inverted "git log --author" or a "git log --exclude-author=botuser", if such as option had existed.

Currently I do the following, shortcuted to a bash alias.

```
git log --format="%H %aE" | grep -v -F botuser@domain | while read hash email; do git log -1 $hash; echo; done | less
```

My question is if there is a less hackish solution to what I want to accomplish?

Comment: On the off chance you do still frequent this site, I suggest you change the accepted answer of this question. Hammer merely told you that it's being considered for inclusion in git, quodlibetor actually provided a solution.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, it is possible now with `git log --author=bot --invert-grep`.

Comment: @larhat Warning: this (`git log --author=bot --invert-grep`) **will not** work anymore, starting [with Git 2.35+ (Q1 2022)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70644305/6309).

Answer (score 65, accepted):

From https://coderwall.com/p/tzdzwa :

```
git log --perl-regexp --author='^((?!excluded-author-regex).*)$'
```

This worked for me.

If you don't want to specify `--perl-regexp` every time you can do:

```
git config --global grep.patternType perl
```

Comment: This requires git 1.8.0 or later.

Comment: Works fine. You could use --perl-regexp instead of changing the global config for the grep pattern type.

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting `fatal: cannot use Perl-compatible regexes when not compiled with USE_LIBPCRE` on mac. I think I need to so this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28587310/5771861

Comment: If you get `cannot use Perl-compatible regexes...` and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28587310/5771861) doesn't help, try `brew upgrade git`. Did the trick for me.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for author emails, only author names.

Comment: Hmm, it seems to be concatenating the author name and email, actually. `git log --perl-regexp --author='^((?!bors.*bors@rust-lang.org).*)$'` does the right thing but `git log --perl-regexp --author='^((?!bors@rust-lang.org).*)$'` does not.

Answer (score 55):

Some other answers reference portions of this, but I had success in my repo using the tactic I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39235609/1740227)

```
 git log --invert-grep --author=<pattern>
```

You can add as many author patterns as needed. In my case, the best pattern was the full email, since it is known to be unique

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: Note: this won't work anymore [with Git 2.35+ (Q1 2022)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70644305/6309)

Answer (score 29):

Warning, [mateor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1740227/mateor)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53623488/6309) won't work anymore with Git 2.35 (Q1 2022).

```
 # WRONG:
 git log --invert-grep --author=<pattern>
```

[quodlibetor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25616/quodlibetor)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20359396/6309) remains valid:

```
git log --perl-regexp --author='^((?!excluded-author-regex).*)$'
```

But: no more  `git log --invert-grep --author=<pattern>` to exclude an author.

"[`git log --invert-grep --author=<name>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2043ce828e8020778c5460eaf7d5a207317c1c09/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L69)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---invert-grep))</sup> used to exclude commits written by the given author, but now "`--invert-grep`" only affects the matches made by the "`--grep=<pattern>`" option.

See [commit 794c000](https://github.com/git/git/commit/794c000267b7bd29024b56e282509a82b31e6fc8) (17 Dec 2021) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2043ce8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2043ce828e8020778c5460eaf7d5a207317c1c09), 05 Jan 2022)</sup>

> ### [`log`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/794c000267b7bd29024b56e282509a82b31e6fc8): let `--invert-grep` only invert `--grep`
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Dotan Cohen</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> The option `--invert-grep` is documented to filter out commits whose messages match the `--grep` filters.
> However, it also affects the header matches (`--author`, `--committer`), which is not intended.
>
> Move the handling of that option to [`grep.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/794c000267b7bd29024b56e282509a82b31e6fc8/grep.c), as only the code there can distinguish between matches in the header from those in the message body.
> If `--invert-grep` is given then enable extended expressions (not the regex type, we just need '[`git grep`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/794c000267b7bd29024b56e282509a82b31e6fc8/Documentation/git-grep.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep))</sup>s `--not` to work), negate the body patterns and check if any of them match by piggy-backing on the `collect_hits` mechanism of `grep_source_1()`.
>
> Collecting the matches in struct `grep_opt` is a bit iffy, but with `"last_shown"` we have a precedent for writing state information to that struct.

---

Why? After an [initial discussion in June 2017](https://public-inbox.org/git/CA+dzEBn4EKzDqS0pCHHsPtGGJc1orf5weKKh0GN-GkE+fVYGcg@mail.gmail.com/T/#u), this was [discussed again in Dec. 2021](https://public-inbox.org/git/xmqqbl1f5c7z.fsf@gitster.g/T/#u):

> ### What did you do before the bug happened?
>
> ```
> $ git log -8 --author=Shachar --grep=Revert --invert-grep
> ```
>
> ### What did you expect to happen?
>
> I expected to see the last 8 commits from `Shachar` that did not have
> the string "`Revert`" in the commit message.
>
> ### What happened instead?
>
> The list of commits included commits by authors other than `Shachar`.
>
> ### What's different between what you expected and what actually happened?
>
> The "`--author`" filter seems to be ignored when the "`--invert-grep`"
> option is used.
> I also tried to change the order of the options, but the results
> remained the same.

Comment: On one hand, passing the invert flag through to the grep powering `--author` was clearly a hack. But on the other, `--invert-grep` is applied to every other pattern, why wouldn't that be true for patterns set with helper flags.

Comment: @mateor I agree. I found your solution more intuitive.

Comment: :'( that's a pitty

Answer (score 17):

Not currently, although [there seems to have been some discussion](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Supporting-quot-v-quot-option-for-git-log-td6402040.html) about supporting a `-v` option in the future, or making the current `git log --not` work for `--author`, `--committer` and `--grep`.

See also: [How to invert `git log --grep` pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602204/how-to-invert-git-log-grep-pattern-or-how-to-show-git-logs-that-dont-match).

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution compatible with Git 2.35+ found in [here](http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/07/18/filtering-by-author-name/)

```
git log --format='%H %an' |  # get a list of all commit hashes followed by the author name
  grep -v Adam |             # match the name but return the lines that *don't* contain the name
  cut -d ' ' -f1 |           # from this extract just the first part of the line which is commit ref
  xargs -n1 git log          # call git log
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, with `--pretty` flag using a format.

- Example:
  `git log --pretty=format:"ID Commit %h, %ar%nThe title was >>%s<<%n"`