# How to compile git with PCRE on Mac?

Tags: git, macos, pcre, pcre2

I need the PCRE for this command - `git log -i -P --all --grep='^(?=.*fix)(?=.*a)(?=.*bug)'`

It shows - fatal: cannot use Perl-compatible regexes when not compiled with USE_LIBPCRE

I tried -

```
brew reinstall pcre git
brew reinstall pcre2 git
```

And the output of the brew config is

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 3.3.16
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 2dc375acc2fe4e089d103171ec8fb06a87d83bb6
Last commit: 2 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: 528cff0f77f4ab9f8bccfae8d148eced81eeb3d5
Core tap last commit: 39 minutes ago
Core tap branch: master
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_CORE_GIT_REMOTE: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 4
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.8 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
CPU: quad-core 64-bit kabylake
Clang: 13.0.0 build 1300
Git: 2.19.0 => /usr/local/bin/git
Curl: 7.77.0 => /usr/bin/curl
macOS: 12.2.1-x86_64
CLT: 13.0.0.0.1.1627064638
Xcode: N/A
```

Also followed the steps from this question - [How to install Git with PCRE support on macOS with Homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055390/how-to-install-git-with-pcre-support-on-macos-with-homebrew)

Comment: What happened when you ran those commands? Did you get an error? If so what is it?

Comment: It still shows - fatal: cannot use Perl-compatible regexes when not compiled with USE_LIBPCRE

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full error message.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055390/how-to-install-git-with-pcre-support-on-macos-with-homebrew

Comment: Check that `git` is your brew installed git. `which git`. Be aware if that the `git` your shell finds might not be the same if you're running `git` in a different context.

Comment: which git shows - /usr/local/bin/git @Schwern

Comment: Did it - @Code-Apprentice

Comment: @joydeba And /usr/local/bin/git is a symlink to /usr/local/Cellar/git/...?

Comment: Yes @Schwern I just checked it.

Comment: did you complete this step? `brew reinstall --with-pcre2 git`

Comment: @RichardBarber It shows - Error: invalid option: --with-pcre2

Comment: Your `git log` command works fine for me. What does `git --version` say? What macOS version are you on? Note: Homebrew `git` is already [built with `USE_LIBPCRE2`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/git.rb#L56).

Comment: `git --version` says - git version 2.19.0. macOS version is Monterey (12.2.1) @fncontroloption

Comment: `brew` should be installing a much later Git version. Perhaps you're running something other than the version `brew` just installed?

Comment: Maybe you have multiple Git versions installed. What's your output for `ls $(brew --prefix)/Cellar/git` and `brew config`?

Comment: `ls $(brew --prefix)/Cellar/git` - 2.35.1

Comment: @fncontroloption Question updated with `brew config` output.

Comment: Your homebrew seems up-to-date, but your git is slightly outdated. `brew update && brew upgrade` should get you up to 2.35.1

Answer (score 1):

According to brew history, `git` was at version `2.19` back in the year 2018. `PCRE2` was optional at the time. Presently, in 2022 we are at `2.35.1` and `PCRE2` comes standard.

To bring your items up-to-date:

```
brew update
brew upgrade
```

Comment: `brew update` and  `brew upgrade` are not working, still the version is 2.19.0.

Comment: brew upgraded these packages only - assimp 5.2.1 -> 5.2.2
hdf5 1.12.1 -> 1.13.0
sqlite 3.37.2 -> 3.38.0
octave 6.4.0_1 -> 6.4.0_2
flac 1.3.3 -> 1.3.4
vtk 9.1.0_2 -> 9.1.0_3
netcdf 4.8.1 -> 4.8.1_1
imagemagick 7.1.0-25 -> 7.1.0-26

Comment: In that case, `brew uninstall git && brew install git`

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, I am posting it here in case anyone needs it

```
  brew link --force git # showed I have another git 
  rm '/usr/local/bin/git' # had to remove it
  brew uninstall git && brew install git
  brew link --overwrite git # then linked
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run git # optional
  git --version
```