# How to invert git log --author=me? (Without using Perl)

Tags: git, git-log

How can I invert

```
git log --author=me
```

to get all commits which are not from me?

Edit: I can not use Perl
*OS: Windows 7, Git Version: 1.9.4*

Comment: possible duplicate of [equivalence of: git log --exclude-author?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889830/equivalence-of-git-log-exclude-author)

Comment: The difference is: I can not use Perl regexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you can see in [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20359396/2082964), you could use a perl regex:

```
git log --perl-regexp --author='^((?!excluded-author-regex).*)$'
```

**EDIT**
a hack if you cannot use perl:

```
git log --oneline --pretty=format:"%h %an %s" | grep -v "Author Name"
```

Comment: This is what I tried. But I " cannot use Perl-compatible regexes when not compiled with USE_LIBPCRE"

Comment: I added a hack to work around this obstacle... don't know if you have grep at your disposal?

Comment: Yes grep is available

Comment: Thanks,  this was the idea i was looking for. Using %an in the format and grep. :-)