# How to exclude several accounts for Git log with date condition?

Tags: git

I’d like to get Git log only users with date condition.
Since in our CI/CD pipeline, some commits automatically added, we’d like to purge them.

For example, we’d like to exclude below system accounts and get Git log after 2022-10-01.

sachiko@XXX.co.jp 
keiko@XXX.co.jp 
iori@XXX.co.jp 
… other 100 user accounts <-- our pick up target 

concourse@XXX.co.jp <-- system account, purge target 
git@localhost  <-- system acount, purge target 
devXXXXau  <-- system acount, purge target

```
trial :
git log --date=iso --pretty=format:"[%ad] %h %an" --author='^(?!concourse@XXX.co.jp|git@localhost|devXXXXau).*$' --perl-regexp --after '2022/10/01'

result:
[2022-11-11 19:40:48 +0900] 463aab83 sachiko<E7><B8><B2><C2><80>--author='^(?!concourse@XXX.co.jp|git@localhost|devXXXXau).*$'
[2022-11-11 19:40:49 +0900] 463aab84 git@localhost<E7><B8><B2><C2><80>--author='^(?!concourse@XXX.co.jp|git@localhost|devXXXXau).*$'
[2022-11-11 19:40:56 +0900] 463aab85 iori<E7><B8><B2><C2><80>--author='^(?!concourse@XXX.co.jp|git@localhost|devXXXXau).*$'
```

We'd like pick up only users log, sachiko and iori, to purge all system log, but it's not working so far.

And also I’d just like to get only “[2022-11-11 19:40:47 +0900] 463aab83 sachiko”, author date, commit hash, author.

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889830/equivalence-of-git-log-exclude-author.

Comment: Instead "exclude many" (even in better form `--author='^((?!concourse|git|dev).*)$'`)` maybe to have "include one"?

Comment: @Lazy Badger thanks for your kind comment. Sorry for my bad example, I'd like to pick up other 100 users' log. I'll edit my sample.

Comment: ACK, cleaner now. For case "pick up a lot, purge a few" please try my shortened regexp. Your code *may not work* due to **unescaped special char in regexp**, namely - dots in email

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @eftshift0 and @Lazy Badger I could exclude several accounts as follows;

```
git log --date=local --pretty=format:"[%ad] %h %an : %s"  --after '2022/10/01' --author="\(concourse@xxxxx.co.jp\)\|\(devxxxxxxau\)\|\(git@localhost\)" --invert-grep
```

Hopefully, it can be a little help for someone.

Comment: `\|\` seems as error for me in regexp "r1 or r2" (escaping of |)