# Find all Git commits from authors whose email is not in certain domain (ex. abc.com)

Tags: regex, git, azure-devops

I'm pushing a large repo into another on Azure DevOps Repos and I'm getting error because one repo policy only allows author with **@abc.com** pattern for email.

> The push was rejected because one or more commits contain author email 'user1@xyz.com' which does not match the policy-specified patterns

When I run the git command below on my window PC I can see the precise check-in from this user1@xyz.com

```
git log --name-only --author="user1@xyz.com"
```

How can I run the git log command to find all commits that are not @abc.com?  is there a built in command in git?

My un-successful attempts so far using regex:

```
git log --name-only --author='@(?!abc\.com)([^.]+\.)+com$' --perl-regexp

git log --name-only --author='^((?!*)abc\.com)$' --perl-regexp
```

Comment: 1. Please check these answers about your task https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74404311/how-to-exclude-several-accounts-for-git-log-with-date-condition + https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889830/equivalence-of-git-log-exclude-author 2. Try to use (and show even unsuccessful results here) simplified regexp with negation

Comment: First skimmed iteration --author='^((?!@abc\.com$')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git log --all --pretty="%h %aE %cE"` will list all author and committer emails for your commits.

You can then process the output however you see fit.

AFAIK there isn't a built-in command to list "the commits whose author do not match that domain".

Comment: It's not command, but 1) option in `git log`, as OP noted 2) this option allow negating, as OP wrote once more

Answer (score 1):

```
git shortlog --all -es | grep -v @xyz.com
```

Explanation:

[`git shortlog --all -es`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog) shows a list of users with their number of commits; like this:

```
  2023  Oleg Broytman <phd@phdru.name>
    60  Test <test@example.org>
```

`grep -v` filters the input by lines that don't contain the pattern.

Comment: It's **The Bad Idea (tm)** suggest to using piping and 2 commands, while *it can be done* entirely inside Git

Comment: @LazyBadger What is your answer? The OP has said a single command doesn't work for him. And no, it's not a bad idea to provide a working solution; esp. in case where other solutions don't work or are incomplete.

Comment: Author made mistake somehow in (regexp), I suppose (need more details from his side). As linked answers in my commend to OP show, his commands *are correct* in common sense and syntax, just overcomplicated in pattern (IMNSHO)