# How to give a pattern for new line in grep?

Tags: bash, grep, newline

How to give a pattern for new line in grep?
New line at beginning, new line at end. Not the regular expression way. Something like \n.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. `new line at the beginning` is a blank line and `new line at end` applies to every line in the file. Can you post an example?

Comment: Actually you can just use `$`. It's somewhat limited, but usable in simple cases.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Usage see item 15.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

`grep` patterns are matched against individual lines so there is no way for a pattern to match a newline found in the input.

However you can find empty lines like this:

```
grep '^$' file
grep '^[[:space:]]*$' file # include white spaces
```

Comment: At least GNU grep has -z option that makes grep break lines by null character. However, it does not seem to support newline or \n in pattern to match newline, see [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grep/+bug/1641092).

Comment: @jarno It supports \n in patterns with the -P flag

Answer (score 114):

try `pcregrep` instead of regular `grep`:

```
pcregrep -M "pattern1.*\n.*pattern2" filename
```

the `-M` option allows it to match across multiple lines, so you can search for newlines as `\n`.

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion. I've used `pcregrep` a LOT the last week.
For example, `pcregrep -lMr "\r\n" *` to recursively find all files that have at least one
CRLF line ending. And after conversion to Unix line endings, I used `pcregrep -lMr "  \n" *`
to find all files having Markdown *soft* line breaks. Very helpful!

Comment: This is the most efficient of all the answers, trying to accomplish this with grep made me waste a day.

Answer (score 44):

Thanks to @jarno I know about the -z option and I found out that when using GNU grep with the -P option, *matching against `\n` is possible*. :)

**Example:**

```
grep -zoP 'foo\n\K.*'<<<$'foo\nbar'
```

Result:

```
bar
```

**Example that involves matching everything including newlines:**

`.*` will not match newlines. To match everything including newlines, use<sup>1</sup> `(.|\n)*`:

```
grep -zoP 'foo\n\K(.|\n)*'<<<$'foo\nbar\nqux'
```

Result:

```
bar
qux
```

<sup>1</sup> Seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33418344

Comment: Great, note that I do not get notification about the "@jarno" in the answer.

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much for sharing!

Comment: Works for me. Thanks a lot.   `grep -zoPnir "dex\n035" ./dir/`

Answer (score 28):

You can use this way...

```
grep -P '^\s$' file
```

- `-P` is used for Perl regular expressions (an extension to POSIX `grep`).
- `\s` match the white space characters; if followed by `*`, it matches an empty line also.
- `^` matches the beginning of the line. `$` matches the end of the line.

Comment: `-P` is a GNU extension. I am fine for using it when the situation calls for it (typically lookahead/lookbehind), but POSIX grep can do this just file with `[[:space:]]`.

Comment: FWIW, Solaris' and BSD's grep manpages (didn't check others) both have a paragraph for `-P`. GNU is quite standard anyway. :)

Comment: From manual page: [-P] This option is not supported in FreeBSD.

Comment: No [-P] for MacOsX either: grep [-abcdDEFGHhIiJLlmnOopqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]] [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color[=when]] [--colour[=when]] [--context[=num]] [--label] [--line-buffered] [--null] [pattern] [file ...]

Comment: @Niccolò You'll want to `brew install grep` to get GNU grep, which is superior in several ways.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193288/how-to-install-and-use-gnu-grep-in-osx

Answer (score 8):

As for the workaround (without using non-portable `-P`), you can temporary replace a new-line character with the different one and change it back, e.g.:

```
grep -o "_foo_" <(paste -sd_ file) | tr -d '_'
```

Basically it's looking for exact match `_foo_` where `_` means `\n` (so `__` = `\n\n`). You don't have to translate it back by `tr '_' '\n'`, as each pattern would be printed in the new line anyway, so removing `_` is enough.

Comment: pardon my ignorance, but is using process substituion not yet another NON posix compatible, hence non-portable feature? in posix shell I could not do `<(p paste -sd_ file )`?

Answer (score 6):

just found

```
grep $'\r'
```

It's using `$'\r'` for c-style escape in Bash.

in [this article](https://superuser.com/questions/194668/grep-to-find-files-that-contain-m-windows-carriage-return)

Comment: carriage return `\r` is not a newline `\n`. If your grepping for windows style line ending you need `\r\n`