# Regular expressions matching exactly one line

Tags: regex, grep

I am pretty new to regular expressions.
I've been trying to use 'grep' alongside with regular expressions to extract a line from a file.
I thought some of you might help:

My file has the lines:

```
c total length of integration
ntotal= 0
c total number of updates
ntotal= 20
c total number of outputs 
ntotal= 10
```

So I was wondering how do I extract the first occurrence of 'ntotal= 0'

I tried with grep `^c.*tot.*\n? 'filename'` , but that did not work.

Any ideas?

Regards,

Abedin

Comment: [`^ntotal=\s*\d+$`](http://regex101.com/r/nL7dK7) or [`^c\s*total.*$`](http://regex101.com/r/mE5tM1)?

Comment: Hi Sam, the first case returns nothing. The second case returns the line starting with 'c'. I want the line after the first occurrence of 'c', that is I want the line immediately following the 'c total length of integration'

Comment: [`^c.*\R\K.*$`](http://regex101.com/r/gQ9uC1) is this what you want? Note it **literally** takes the next line, so it won't work with whitespace. Let me know if this needs to be modified, otherwise I can post as an answer w/explanation.

Comment: What this last thing did was to skip everything and jumped over the line after 'ntotal = 10' and printed its content

Comment: Hmm, I've never looked into the differences of `grep` expressions, so I think there is a problem there. Try making the `.*` lazy with a `?`: [`^c.*?\R\K.*$`](http://regex101.com/r/xU1vN1)

Comment: Hi again, I tried your last suggestion ^c.*?\R\K.*$ but this time it did not return anything.

Comment: I now see that my post has been edited. Just to clarify something - there is a blank line after all instances of 'ntotal'.

Comment: Ah, I just read up on `grep` expressions and turns out they [match line-by-line](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12652676/703229). So it is impossible to look at the next line, the best you can do is just see if it starts with `ntotal=`.

Answer (score 2):

`grep` has a flag `-m` that sets the maximum number of occurrences to match,

thus

```
grep -m 1 -P '^ntotal *= *[0-9]+$' < filename
```

Starting the expression with `^` means that this is the start of a line, `$` means the end of the line. The `-P` flag means that extended regular expression patterns are enabled (Perl style).

I've added `*` so that there is an arbitrary amount of spaces between `ntotal` and `=` allowed (zero or more).

`< filename` means that you use the content of the file called `filename` as input.

Comment: Don't think this does exactly what OP wanted, but I think its the best you can do with `grep` and will give the intended output.

Comment: But regexes are, especially when it comes to newlines etc., not standardized. For instance C# has special flags to allow new line parsing, `sed` uses special characters, etc.

Comment: Yea, I had never really worked with `grep` expressions but just read that it goes line-by-line so there really isn't any new line parsing (making OP's direct request somewhat impossible). I gave a +1 as I think it does answer the question, I also learned about the `-m` flag.

Comment: That worked!!! But I am still wondering if there is a way to tell 'grep' to match next line after a given line. For instance, something like:   grep -m 1 -P '^c.*tot.*$\r'

Comment: I am sorry guys. I just saw your comments! Perhaps, it is impossible with 'grep' to parse the next line after a given line. However, I'd like to thank all of you for your help!

Comment: @user3578925: as sam already pointed out, `grep` goes line-by-line. So you can't match a string that spans over two or more lines. If you want to do this, you need to use `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: Thank you guys! I think I should sit down and learn sed or awk. Kind regards, Abedin.

Answer (score 1):

To get the first `ntotal` you can use `awk` like this:

```
awk '/ntotal/ {print $0;exit}' file
ntotal= 0
```

It search for `ntotal`, if found, print the line and then exit.