# Why doesn't grep end with this regexp?

Tags: regex, unix, grep, pcre

I'm trying to analyze a bunch of C# files I have, with grep, to match a particular type of for-loop. Specifically, anything that looks like the following would match:

```
for (int i = 0; i < foo.Length; i++)
{
    foo[i] = bar[i];
}
```

I tried installing [pcregrep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12678300/4077294) after I learned grep didn't support multiline, but it's not working out. Here is my (admittedly very sloppy) regexp:

```
pcregrep -rlM "for (int i = 0; i < [A-Za-z]*\.Length; i++)\n[ *]\{\n[ *][A-Za-z]*\[i\] = [A-Za-z]*\[i\];\n[ *]\}"
```

I ran this command about 10 minutes ago, and it's still running (albeit at very low CPU usage, surprisingly). Am I doing something wrong / Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: If you escape the parenthesis `\(`, `\)`. It will at least avoid saving items

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Hm, I just tried that and it's still hanging.

Comment: I wrote it in a different way: `for\s*\([^)]+\)\s*{\s*\w+\[\w+\]\s*=\s*\w+\[\w+\];\s*}`

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Thanks! I just tested out your pattern and it seems to work a lot better than mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pcregrep`, unlike `grep`, doesn’t infer “use the current directory” from `-r`, so it’s waiting for input, which gives it the appearance of hanging. Specify the path explicitly:

```
pcregrep -rlM … .
```

Comment: I probably should have realized that earlier, haha. Thanks!