# Grep any whitespace character including newline in single pattern

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to make 'perfect' command to show any .php file in dir or subdirs that contain `eval` code.

Since there are many many false positives, I'm after solution that would strip at least most obvious of them - so my target is:

**word eval, followed by any whitepace char including newline zero to unlimited times, followed by open bracket char `(`;**

Here are my shots:

`find . -type f -exec grep -l "eval\s*(" {} \; | grep ".php"`

Works great **but** somehow `\s*` here doesn't match newline characters, so

```
eval

("some nasty obfuscated code");
```

is bellow the radar.

I've also tried with:

`find . -type f -exec grep -l "eval[[:space:]]*(" {} \; | grep ".php"`

with same results.

Comment: Perhaps this might help you: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652568/how-to-give-a-pattern-for-new-line-in-grep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652568/how-to-give-a-pattern-for-new-line-in-grep)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Simple Version:

For simplicity sake, to cater for your need, but using `awk` instead of `grep` (if this is possible), then for php files in `/tmp/`, you could simply;

```
awk -v RS="^$" '/eval[[:space:]]*\(/ { print FILENAME }' /tmp/*.php
```

And that will print the files that match.

If you need to use the output of `find`:

```
find /tmp/ -iname "*.php" -print | while read file ; do awk -v RS="^$" '/eval[[:space:]]*\(/ { print FILENAME }' "$file" ; done
```

The above is simple and works even with busybox and basic versions of awk.

### Alternate (With matches)

This part of the answer may seem absurd to some, but enough experience with searching for whitespace, and doing serialisation in the shell, the amount of "gotcha's" become evident, and the need for a working solution causes the preference for built-in one liners to take a back seat.

This might also help others stumbling across a similar need, but requiring easy to read line previews, maybe for parsing, or simplicity:

**NOTE 1:** This solution works in sh/ash/busybox as well as bash (the external binary `xxd` would still be needed)

**NOTE 2:** For **BSD** grep, substitute `-P` with `-E`.  Using `-E` on a GNU grep that has support for `-P`, seems to not yield the same lookahead matches

### Example Test File

Take this test file (with special characters notated in place), plus 2 other test files that are located in /tmp/ for this example:

[image: eval file]

```
find /tmp/ -iname "*.php" -print \
| while read file ; do hexdump -ve '1/1 " %02X"' "$file" \
| sed -E "s/($)/ 0A/g" \
| grep -P -o "65 76 61 6C( 09| 0A| 0B| 0C| 0D| 20)*? 28 22.+?0A" \
| sed -E -e 's/ //g' \
| sed -E -e 's/(0A)+([^$])/20\2/g' \
| sed -E -e 's/(09|0B|0C|0D|20)+/20/g' \
| xxd -r -p \
| grep -i "eval" && printf "$file matches\n\n" ; done
```

Will return the matches, from eval, *to the end of the line where the `("` was matched*, substituting line breaks and spaces for a *single space* for readability :

```
eval ("some nasty obfuscated code (LF / LINE FEED)");
eval ("some nasty obfuscated code (HT / TAB)");
eval ("some nasty obfuscated code (SP / SPACE)");
eval ("some nasty obfuscated code (FF / FORM FEED)");
eval ("some nasty obfuscated code (CR / CARRIAGE RETURN)");
eval ("some nasty obfuscated code (VT / VERTICAL TAB)");
eval ("some nasty obfuscated code (LF > HT > FF > CR > LF > LF > HT > VT > LF > HT > SP)");
eval ("some nasty obfuscated code (VT / VERTICAL TAB)");
/tmp/eval.php matches

eval ("some nasty obfuscated code (LF / LINE FEED)");
/tmp/eval_no_trailing_line_feed.php matches

eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
/tmp/eval_w3_example.php matches
```

For just the file matches using this method (maybe to allow for a "-v" option for example), just change `grep -i` on the last line to `grep -iq`

### Explanation:

`find /tmp/ -iname "*.php" -print \` : Find .php files in /tmp/

`| while read file ; do hexdump -ve '1/1 " %02X"' "$file" \` : hexdump each resulting file, and output in single space separated bytes (to avoid any matching from the second character of one byte to the first char of another byte)

`| sed -E "s/($)/ 0A/g" \` : Put a single `0A` (line feed) at the very end of the file that matches - This means it will match a file that does not have a trailing line feed (sometimes can cause some issues with text processing)

`| grep -P -o "65 76 61 6C( 09| 0A| 0B| 0C| 0D| 20)*? 28 22.+?0A" \` : Return only match (note that `grep` adds a line break to each match)

- 6576616C : eval
- 09 : horizontal TAB
- 0A : line feed
- 0B : vertical TAB
- 0C : form feed
- 0D : carriage return
- 20 : plane SPACE
- 2822 : ("

`| sed -E -e 's/ //g' \` : Remove all spaces between bytes (may not have been needed in the end)

`| sed -E -e 's/(0A)+([^$])/20\2/g' \` : Look for any repeated occurrences of `0A` (line feed), as long as they are not the line feed at the end of the line, and replace them with a single space (`20`)

`| sed -E -e 's/(09|0B|0C|0D|20)+/20/g' \` : Look for any of the white space characters above, and replace them with a space, for readability

`| xxd -r -p \` : Revert back from hex

`| grep -i "eval" && printf "$file matches\n\n" ; done` : Print the match, and the file name (the `&&` means that `printf` will only print the file match, if the output of `grep` was `0` (success), therefore it won't simply print every file in the loop. (as noted before, adding `-q` into this grep will still evaluate for the purpose of `printf`, but will not output the matching lines.

Answer (score 1):

If I did understand you correct, **I believe this line here to be what you're looking for:**

`find . -name '*.php' -exec grep -Ezl 'eval\s*\(' {} +`

**the `-z` is what you've been missing**, see explanation below.
and of course you could give the `find` command whatever other root rather than `.` and just add arguments and conditions according to where you are looking in and what you are looking for.

## That was it. From here on, explanations:

### The `find` command

It would probably be faster in most cases to first search for files with .php extension, and then search only within these files for your regular expression. The `-name '*.php'` part gives us this behavior by searching only for files with a file name ending with '.php'.

`-exec` allows us to execute a command using the output of the find command (file names). We are using it in order to execute grep for all php files.

This syntax `{} +` in the end of the line, creates one long list of file names as arguments for the grep command, instead of executing grep separately for every file.

### The `grep` command

`-E`: Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (copied from the grep man page)

`-z`: Treat the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte instead of a newline (grep man page). That means that **for a normal textual file, the whole file would be treated as one long line. This behavior allows you to use multi-lined regular expressions.**

`-l`: tells grep to only show the filenames for all the files matching the search, and not to show the matching lines.

### The *regular expression*:

`'eval'` just matches the word eval.
`'\s'` matches any whitespace character, and the `'*'` after it means it could appear zero or more times. This `'\('` matches an actual bracket, which in this case needs escaping (and that's what the `\` is for).

have fun!

Comment: The only thing with `-z` is that it will only work in GNU versions of grep, and in a huge list of files, this invocation could return `argument list too long`