# Grepping for overlapping pattern matches

Tags: regex, unix, grep

This is what I'm running

```
grep -o ',[tcb],' <<< "r,t,c,q,c b,b,"
```

The output is

```
,t,
,b,
```

But I want to get

```
,t,
,c,
,b,
```

(I do not want the b without a preceding , or the c without a trailing , to be matched)

Because ,[tcb], should be found in 'r",t,"c,q b,b,' 'r,t",c,"q b,b,' and 'r,t,c,q b",b,"'

But it seems that when the , is included in the first pattern match then grep does not look for this in the second instance of the pattern match

Is there a way around this or is grep not meant to do this

Comment: `grep` consumes the input. What this means is when `grep` takes `,t,` the `,` before `c` is already consumed therefore the next token `c,` does not qualify. @anubhava already has a solution before I can post one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `awk` instead of `grep` for this with record separator as comma:

```
awk -v RS=, '/^[tcb]$/{print RS $0 RS}' <<< "r,t,c,q,c b,b,"

,t,
,c,
,b,
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep` with a `Perl` RE, which allows non-capturing look-behind and look-ahead patterns to extract letters surrounded by commas. You can then restore the separators just as you need them as by:

```
grep -o -P '(?<=,)[tcb](?=,)' <<< "r,t,c,q,c b,b,"|while read c; do echo ",$c,"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

The awk solution is nice. I have another with sed+grep:

```
echo  "r,t,c,q,c b,b," | sed "s/,/,,/g" | grep -o ',[tcb],'

,t,
,c,
,b,
```