# Sourcetree log commits of an author or a group of authors

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

Is it possible to filter the SourceTree log view of commits by one or a group of authors?

I know that using the terminal it is possible as the next post, but I don't know how to configure it in SourceTree:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22971024/4751165

But most (all) in my project use SourceTree, also we share a repository with other team and each team only wants to see his team commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SourceTree on OSX then go to Search View (press <kbd>Cmd-3</kbd>), select "User" in the "Search" dropdown, enter (a fragment of) the author name in the big search edit box and press Enter.

It also accepts regular expressions but, for some reason I don't know, it seems to use `\|` instead of `|`.

I don't know if (and how) this works on SourceTree for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Windows:

- go to Search View (or Ctrl+3)
- select "Authors" in the drop-down
- type the name of the author in the search box, and press Enter

**As result**: the list of commits for the given author will be returned:

[image: print screen]