# Git shortlog exclude comments starting with string

Tags: git, controls, version

I am trying to count the commits by each author but like to exclude commits whos messages begin with the word TEST.. for example.

I am currently doing the following to get the list.

```
 git shortlog -s -n --all
```

This brings back my counts but drilling into each authors commits shows a lot which start with TEST.. I would like to get the count without these commits included.. is this possible?

Comment: what you talking about is inversion of `git log --grep=<pattern>` searching for a commit which does not contains a particular pattern . i found this thread you might find useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602204/how-to-invert-git-log-grep-pattern-or-how-to-show-git-logs-that-dont-matc

Answer (score 1):

The following one-liner will work. I am using Git Bash, which is up to version 1.9.4.

```
git shortlog $(git log --pretty=format:"%H %s" | grep -v 'stuff' | cut -c -40) --no-walk
```

If you have a later version that accepts the `--invert-grep` option you can probably use the following. (I noticed that shortlog seems to take all the same arguments as log, but it is undocumented.) I cannot test this though.

```
git shortlog --grep 'stuff' --invert-grep
```